# in-memory FILE* (without disk access)

Tags: c, fread, stdio

We have library which accepts FILE* (CImg). For performance reason we wish to handle data already in memory without accessing a disk. Target platform is windows which unfortunately does not support fmemopen (and funopen)

```
char* buf = new char[sz];

FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\test.dat", "wb");
int r = setvbuf(fp, buf, _IOFBF, sz);

r = fwrite(src_buf, 1, sz, fp);     // Here r contains right size


fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t sz2 = ftell(fp);             // sz2 contains right size as well
rewind(fp);

// Test (something like this actually is somewhere deep inside library)
char* read_buf = new char[sz];
r = fread(read_buf, 1, sz, fp);     // Zero!
```

Final fread() can't read anything... Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is this tagged with C++? This looks like C.

Comment: Is there any possibility of of using a memory mapped file?

Comment: `fp` was opened write-only.

Comment: How are you placing the data in memory?    Without knowing that, nobody can give advice on how to read it from memory (whether using a `FILE *` or any other means).

Comment: Peter, we receive (char* src_buf, size_t sz) - from database or network, it doesn't matter. Other means are unlikely due to certain library interface

Comment: Have you tried a ramdisk or even an SSD drive? And depending on how this library reads from the `FILE *` that you pass to it, simply setting a huge buffer value may work, too.

Comment: 3rd party `fmemopen()` implementations exist for Windows, for example [this one](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/msys2-runtime/ci/f21dc72d306bd98e55a08461a9530c4b0ce1dffe/tree/newlib/libc/stdio/fmemopen.c) in MinGW.

Comment: You open fp as "wb" and then try to read from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our specific case we found CImg plugin doing the thing.

As of a sample in an original question - at least MSVC runtime flushes written content to disk itself. So it isn't a valid replace for fmemopen()

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because you opened with "wb" (write-only) instead of "wb+" (read + write)

[fopen() function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)

To help further, you can #include errno.h and print out the error code and string.

```
printf( "errno: %d, error:'%s'\n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped us with reading but still results flushing data to disk. Probably RAM drive will be solution in our case

Comment: @Victor look at the C runtime sources for snprintf. IIRC, it does a fake FILE over an in memory buffer. Don't have a windows box any more of I'd find a better reference.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Snaipe/fmem is a wrapper for different platform/version specific implementations of in-memory files

It tries in sequence the following implementations:

- open_memstream.
- fopencookie, with growing dynamic buffer.
- funopen, with growing dynamic buffer.
- WinAPI temporary memory-backed file.

When no other mean is available, fmem falls back to tmpfile()